# Creating nodes and edges

Tags: python, graph, time-limit-exceeded

I'm looking for a way to optimize this piece of code in Python.

`all_users` holds all the Twitter users and `friends_ids` is an array of IDs.

```
g = Graph(directed=True)
all_users = users.find({}, { 'id_str' : 1, 'friends_ids' : 1}) # This is from MongoDb

names = []
edges = []
print 'Processing first 1000 batch'
for idx, user in enumerate(all_users):
    if idx % 1000 == 0 and idx != 0:
        print 'Processing ' + str(idx) + ' batch'
    names.append(str(user['id_str']))
    for friend_id in user['friends_ids']:
        edges.append((user['id_str'], str(friend_id)))
        if not str(friend_id) in names:
            names.append(str(friend_id))

print len(names)
print len(edges)
```

`all_users` has 4k records but each of the user has at least 10k of `friends_ids`. In order to create a graph I need a list of nodes which I have in `names` and list of edges `edges`.

The format of `edges` would be `[(node1, node2), (node2, node3), ...]`, which means that `node1` connects to `node2` and `node2` connect to `node3`. I'm not sure why but this script takes almost full 10 min to run. So, I'm looking for a way to optimize this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this minor variation over your script, that will probably have a dramatic effect on performance:

```
names = set()
edges = []

for idx, user in enumerate(all_users):
    if idx and not idx % 1000:
        print('Processing {} batch',format(idx))
    user_id = str(user['id_str'])
    names.add(user_id)
    for friend_id in user['friends_ids']:
        friend_id = str(friend_id)
        edges.append((user_id, friend_id))
        names.add(friend_id)
```

The main modification is making `names` a set, not a list, Your script is checking membership of every `friend_id` in `names`, an operation that takes time linear in the size of `names`. In contrast, membership in a set is done in constant time.

If you need `names` to be a list, simply do:

```
names = list(names)
```

after the processing is completed.

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
if not str(friend_id) in names:
    names.append(str(friend_id))
```

`names` is a `list`. Lookup in a list is linear time, and `str` comparison is more expensive than int comparison to boot. Instead, use a different structure:

```
names = set()
...
names.add(friend_id)
```

`set` lookup is constant time, and sticking with integers means that we can save time on the hashing too. With a few million lookups, that's going to make a big impact.